# Power BI / M / Power Query -- Concatenate columns into new column with line breaks

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'd like to combine 4 columns into a single column with line breaks to save space on a table visualization.

I have a data table with 4 columns with strings in them.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dogs | cats | mice | fish |

I'd like to concat each record into a single column with headers and line breaks, so it becomes:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dogs | cats | mice | fish | Col1: dogs Col2: cats Col3: mice Col4: fish |

I'll then put Col5 in the table by itself to save space in the visualization.

I've seen references to using "#(cr)" or "#(lf)" or &Character.FromNumber(10)& but I haven't been able to get anything working.

Current Code:

```
ALLDetails = 
IF(
    ISBLANK([Col1])
    ,"Col1: N/A" 
    ,"Col1: " & [Col1]
)
& --Need linebreak here
IF(
    ISBLANK([Col2])
    ,"Col2: N/A" 
    ,"Col2: " & [Col2]
)
```

TIA!

### Edit because there's always and edit...

The logic to include N/A's in there for blank entries would be helpful if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this (M language in transform tab):

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each "Col1:" & [Col1] &Character.FromNumber(10)& "Col2:" & [Col2]&Character.FromNumber(10)& "Col3:" & [Col3])
```

[image]

> let
> Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSslPL1bSUUpOLAFRuZnJqUAqLbM4Qyk2FgA=",
> BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type
> nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Col1 =
> _t, Col2 = _t, Col3 = _t, Col4 = _t]),
> #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", type text}, {"Col3", type text}, {"Col4", type
> text}}),
> #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each "Col1:" & [Col1] &Character.FromNumber(10)& "Col2:" &
> [Col2]&Character.FromNumber(10)& "Col3:" & [Col3]) in
> #"Added Custom"

UPDATE

With IF statement:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
let 
c1 = if [Col1] = "" then "" else "Col1:" & [Col1] &Character.FromNumber(10) ,
c2 = if [Col2] = "" then "" else "Col2:" & [Col2]&Character.FromNumber(10) ,
c3 = if [Col3] = "" then "" else "Col3:" & [Col3]&Character.FromNumber(10)
in c1 & c2 & c3 )
```

[image]

Comment: This is really close - is it possible to also do the =IF(ISBLANK()) check that I have in the code block for missing entries?

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 2):

If you loaded the 4 columns into powerquery you could add column ... custom column .. with an M code formula as below. Applies to any number of columns, that part is not hard coded

To maintain nulls:

```
= Text.Combine(
let contents=List.Transform(Record.ToList(_), each if _ = null then "N/A" else _),
columns=Table.ColumnNames(Source)  in 
List.Transform(
List.Positions(contents),
each columns{_} & ": " &contents{_}
),"#(lf)" )
```

To remove nulls:

```
= Text.Combine(
List.Transform(    
let contents=List.Transform(Record.ToList(_), each if _ = null then "N/A" else _),
columns=Table.ColumnNames(Source)  in 
List.Transform(
List.Positions(contents),
each columns{_} & ": " &contents{_})
,  each if Text.Contains(_,"N/A") then null else _)
,"#(lf)" )
```

Note, when you load the data back, you need to turn on word wrap or it won't display properly

Comment: Thanks! Microsoft not helping us with cross-platform functions here. This is in PowerBI, not Excel -- Still applicable in PBI?

Comment: @Gondi Power query code is exactly the same whether accessed from Excel or from Power BI.  In PBI, look for `Home=>Transform`

Answer (score 0):

Use this if your table has null values

= Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Col5", each 
let  
c1 = if [Col1] = null then "Col1: N/A" &Character.FromNumber(10)  else "Col1:"& [Col"] &Character.FromNumber(10) , 
c2 = if [Col2] = null then "Col2:N/A" &Character.FromNumber(10)  else "Col2: " & [Col2"] &Character.FromNumber(10) , 
c3 = if [Col3] = null then "Col3:N/A"&Character.FromNumber(10)  else "Col3: " & [Col3"]&Character.FromNumber(10) ,  
c4 = if [Col4] = null then "Col4: N/A"&Character.FromNumber(10)  else "Col4: " & [Col4"]&Character.FromNumber(10)  
in c1 & c2 & c3 & c4)